# How do I make a variable detect if it is greater than or less than another one?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

I am currently learning Python, and I decided to build a small "Guess the Number" type of game. I am using the random feature, and trying to make it so it will detect if the user's input is equal the the random number. This is my code:

```
irand = randrange(1, 10)
while True:
    number = input ("Pick a number 1-10: ")
    if number < irand:
        print ("    ")
        print ("That's too high, try again.")
    if number > irand:
        print ("    ")
        print ("That's too low, try again.")
    if number == irand:
        print ("    ")
        print ("You got it right! You won!")
        break
```

I am not exactly sure how to make it detect if `number` is equal to, less than or greater than `irand`. Any help? Thank you! :)

Comment: Is this python2.x or python3.x?  `input` behaves differently on those . . .

Comment: As a side note: don't put a space between a function name and the parentheses around its arguments; it looks a little off and makes it a little harder to read your code. Also, `print("    ")` doesn't do anything visibly different than just `print()`. (If you have a program reading its output instead of a person, it's different, but to a person, a space looks like nothing was typed there.)

Comment: Please explain explicitly what you're asking, providing the error/problem will help others who may have the same problem later one

Answer (score 6):

Your code to check "equal to, less than, or greater than" is correct, but you've got a problem *earlier* in the code.

In Python (3.0 and later), [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string. So, you're comparing `number`, a string, to `irand`, a number. Some languages might convert one way or the other automatically, but that can be confusing,*, so Python refuses to do so, and instead raises a `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`.

The solution is to parse the input into a number, like this:

```
number = int(number)
```

This will raise a `ValueError` if the user gives you invalid input, like the letter `c` instead of a number from 1 to 10. If you want to deal with that more nicely, you use a `try` statement.

As a side note, you probably want `elif` instead of `if`. If you've got everything right, this doesn't make any difference, but if you've made a mistake, it helps catch the mistake.

So, putting it all together:

```
while True:
    number = input("Pick a number 1-10: ")
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
        continue
    if number < irand:
        print("    ")
        print("That's too high, try again.")
    elif number > irand:
        print("    ")
        print("That's too low, try again.")
    else:
        print("    ")
        print("You got it right! You won!")
        break
```

(Notice that I used `continue` in the `except` clause, so we skip over the rest of the loop and don't have to worry about `number` not being a number anymore. We could also move the whole loop into an `else` cause on the `try`, or add an `isinstance` check on each `if`, etc., but that gets a bit clumsy.)

---

<sub>* Consider comparing the string `"2"` to the number `10`. A language that converts the string to a number will say that `2 < 10`; a language that converts the number to a string will say that `"10" < "2"`. Neither one is "right" or "wrong", but both are surprising half the time…</sub>

Comment: you could also use `else:` instead of/in addition to `'    continue'` and indent the following conditions appropriately.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's already explained in the answer: "We could also move the whole loop body into an `else` clause on the `try`, or…"

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```
while True:
    number = input("Pick a number 1-10: ")
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
        continue
    if number > 10:
        print("    ")
        print("That's too high, try again.")
    elif number < 1:
        print("    ")
        print("That's too low, try again.")
    else:
        print("    ")
        print("You got it right! You won!")
        break
```